# DbMigrator doesn't run the Seed method, How to run it?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm using Entity Framework 6. I'm using `DbMigrator` to do migrations. But unfortunately, running `migrator.Update()` doesn't execute the `Seed` method. How can I run it?

Comment: Can you show your Configuration.cs class?

Comment: @DylanSlabbinck It's a simple configuration. The only point is that it is inherited from a base class and the `Seed` is calling `base.Seed` which has the initialization code.

Answer (score 2):

Try including this, it checks for pending changes in the migrations

```
public Configuration()
{
    AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;

    var dbMigrator = new DbMigrator(this);

    pendingMigrationsExist = dbMigrator.GetPendingMigrations().Any();

    if (pendingMigrationsExist)
    {
        dbMigrator.Update();
    }
}
```